# Fourier Motzkin Elimination and totally unimodularity

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, total-unimodularity, fourier-motzkin

Suppose   $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb R^m$, and $A$ is totally unimodular (TUM).

For the system  $$Ax\leq b,$$

suppose I use  Fourier-Motzkin elimination to eliminate first $k$ variables $(x_1,...,x_k)$,  $1\leq k<n$ and obtain the new system

$$A'x'\leq b'$$

Can I show that TUM is closed under Fourier-Motzkin eliminations, i.e. $A'$ is also TU?